# Issues deploying metadata to a scratch org when it contains org specific data

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I have an issue where a some reports and a custom report folder were created in production but I need to add them to version control so that it can be properly managed within the source of truth. I have pulled down the metadata and convert it to source where it now resides in the following:

`force-app/main/default/reports/Custom_Reports.reportFolder-meta.xml`

Unfortunately when I attempt to push this to a scratch org like so:

`sfdx force:source:push -u test`

I get the following error: `In field: sharedTo - no User named first.last@mydomain.com found`

The obvious answer seems to be that my email is stored directly in the metadata like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>Manage</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>first.last@mydomain.com</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>User</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <name>DPC Reports</name>
</ReportFolder>
```

So how do I work around this? The data setting is stored in the metadata and that value is going to change from org to org so I will have deployment issue every time if the org doesn't contain that user email.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a user and folder permissions then execute the below command to create a user in the scratch org with same username before you run sfdx force:source:push

```
sfdx force:user:create username=first.last@mydomain.com email=<emailofuser>
```

Alternatively you can make it public Folder just to get the scratch org creation going .

To do this modify your metaxml for ReportFolder as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ReportFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <accessType>Public</accessType>
    <publicFolderAccess>ReadWrite</publicFolderAccess>
      <name>DPC Reports</name>
  </ReportFolder>
```

In your PROD org or packaging you can manually turn on Sharing via config.

Comment: Anyway to get around the following error?
`ERROR:  There are no available user licenses for the user profile "Standard User"`

Comment: Sounds like you don't have enough license for that .How many users have you created in scratch org ?Scratch orgs have limited licenses

Comment: There is a pilot program for org shape, you can use that to get an org replica of your PROD org .

Comment: I'm in the pilot and I'm using it effectively but this is not something that it handles. The users created have a randomly generated alpha# and domain is replaced with "example.com" like this `nick.worth.kfnwbm1fiiaa@example.com`

Comment: Actually that is the username... the email is just domain replacement: `nick.worth@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You could first pull up data from your production using [sfdx tree export commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm) and some admin users and/or since you're getting in to issues while creating new users as suggested by Mohith in his answer above for the time being you could open up a text-editor like Sublime and find and replace all occurrences in all files inside src folder of *first.last@mydomain.com* with your *scratch org username*.

I know it's not the most elegant solution out there but at least gets rid of the deployment errors. If you're using a CI system, you could configure a shell script to do the same for you.

For advanced uses you could come up with a regex for matching *@mydomain.com and then replace all the occurrences with a single click. Sublime's find and replace features are really mature and could help you with this in minutes.